# Can one or two spelling mistakes in a statement of purpose hurt your chances for graduate school?

Tags: graduate-admissions, graduate-school, statement-of-purpose

I am wondering can spelling one or two wrong words in SOP hurt chance of getting accepted to graduate school? There might be a mistake about spelling one of my professor's name wrong.

Comment: *Hurt your chances* as in "having a non-zero chance of being detrimental to your application"? Probably yes. As in "being the sole, or even a deciding reason for your rejection"? Very likely no.

Comment: If the professor is on the admissions committee, you are, as we say, scrod.  Otherwise, there are many names spelled in idiosyncratic ways; possibly no one will ever notice.

Comment: @Bob: I just finished my semester's teaching and got several emails saying "Thanks, Professor Clarke!"  I wish the students were more attentive to my not-so-difficult-to-spell name, but I'm obviously not going to ding them in any way for it.  I think the poor impression caused by misspelling people's names is much more subtle than that.

Comment: @Pete: I think the circumstances are different between students finishing a class and someone applying to a graduate program.  However, I have an even easier name than yours, and so it mostly doesn't get mangled.

Comment: @Bob: Yes, they are different: my students had four months to learn my name!  I would feel honorbound not to hold a name misspelling against a graduate applicant.  If someone is applying for a job, then misspelling my name becomes worse because they are presumably dropping my name because of familiarity with my work and the misspelling vitiates that.  In fields in which prospective grad students are supposed to have deep familiarity with the faculty at their program, maybe something similar would apply.  Even so, this is a pretty forgivable offense.

Comment: Uhhh, Pete... now that I think about it, you teach in *Clarke County,* which may account for at least some mistakes with your name.  So, maybe even more forgivable in your case than in general.  (And I agree that it's forgivable in general, but more in some cases than others.)

Answer (score 8):

We once had an applicant for graduate study in mathematics whose statement of purpose explained why he wanted to become a "mathematition". This was not regarded favorably by the admissions committee.  On the other hand, a misspelling of a professor's name might not even be noticed; it depends to some extent on whether the professor's name is "Blagoveshchenskaya" or "Smith".